# Invitation for a Chinese writing contest and asking recommendation for software that screens characters

Tags: software

There is a Chinese Writing Contest just launched, inviting contestants to write something using only 320 characters. The contest closes on Sep 30. Great prizes have line up.
Details are here:
https://www.mslmaster.com/index.php/8-contest/196-chinese-writing-contest
Anyone who is interested, do enter.

My question is:
To check the character requirement, I’m looking for a software which can screen characters and can filter characters out which are not included in the list, if any.

I’ve checked with Imron. His Chinese Text Analyzer can do this, with a bit of manoeuvre.

Does anyone know any software which is easier to use? Ideally, copy and paste, and press a button, so that each contestant can have a quick check before submitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a simple tool to check whether your writing contains the allowed characters only:

https://bettyjj.github.io/limited-characters/

I copied the allowed characters from the contest page you linked and added some common punctuation marks because otherwise they will be listed as not allowed. You can edit the allowed characters field however you like it.

Caveat: This is a really simple tool, so it can't deal with complexities like special characters which have two pronunciations. They are all just allowed characters.

Comment: Thank you! That's fantastic. I added 《》and pasted a random paragraph, and it worked well for screening characters. Perhaps it is too much to ask about the special characters.

Comment: @XuehongZhang You have to analyze the meaning of the sentences to understand which pronunciation is being used. Considering that the articles will be written by learners and probably will have grammatical mistakes and other errors, it is almost impossible to analyze correctly with an algorithm.

Comment: Absolutely. That part will have to be done by humans. Yours works well. I have added the link to the page, along with another solution I've got. Check it out. https://www.mslmaster.com/index.php/8-contest/196-chinese-writing-contest Also, can you add these punctuations: 《》......

Comment: @XuehongZhang OK, I've added the punctuations. I checked the other solution and found it very clever. Today I learned. :)